# What's happening RE Blender Player? Has it been discontinued?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm a bit out of the loop, but my Mac Software update client says Blender Player has been discontinued. The current (last?) version of Blender Player is 2.79, file build date 9/14/2017.

I'm wondering what the story is behind this? I looked through the [release notes](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-81/) going back to V 2.73 on the official Blender website and did a search via DuckDuckGo (my preferred search engine) and did not find any mention about what's going on with the Blender Player, and I looked deep clicking on "read more" on closely related topics on version [2.79](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-79/) and [2.78](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-78/).

Comment: This post is mis-tagged, I would have added tag "Player" but do not have enough rank to do so, and couldn't post without adding at least one tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender Player was a part of the Blender Game engine, which relies on Blender Internal Render engine.

Blender Internal Render engine was dropped due to the fact that its render aproach was quite outdated and with the release of Eevee as the new *physically based* real-time render engine, the developers would have had to take care of three render engines (Blender Internal, Cycles and Eevee).

Depending on what you want to do with Blender Player, there might be alternative solutions with [UPBGE](https://upbge.org/) and [Armory3D](https://armory3d.org) (no MacOS support, afaik)